Generalize/Denoise Multipolygons
I am looking for any Python function, that is able to denoise the area to become more spatially homogenous. In other words, I would like to vanish all small polygons beyond some tolerance.
Maybe something like Fast Fourier Transform in graphical software?
I was not able to find any useful script for this.


Would something like the following work: 1. find all polygons with area < thresh. 2. For each polygon, get the category of the largest adjacent polygon. 3. dissolve on categories. this might need to be recursed if you've lots of small polys surrounded by small polys...

If this was me and doing it in ArcPro, BEFORE I convert it into polygons I would run a majority filter on the source raster. I would look within the open source libraries you used to find an equivalent tool/function.

@Hornbydd Yes the combination of Scipi + GDAL/Rasterio is nice and working. Whitebox tools seem to be more difficult. Now only one more thing is not to use NAN values during filtering. ;-)

Possibly not exactly the same question, but I think the answer could help you out anyway: reclassify_neighbours.
